# how to print a 2d battleship game

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a printed battleship map for player one. this is the code that I made.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define W  '~'
#define H  '*'
#define M  'm'

#define C     'c'
#define B     'b'
#define R     'r'
#define S     's'
#define D     'd'
typedef int boolean;
enum {false,true};
typedef struct {
int aim;
char visuals;
}Space;
typedef struct{
int size;
int type;
}Ship;
Space player1Side[10][10];
Space player2Side[10][10];
Ship s, *nS;
int a, b;
char l;
void printBoard() {
 for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    printf("         | ");
    for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {

        if (player1Side[x][y].aim != 0) {
            printf("%c", player1Side[x][y].visuals);
        }
        else {
            switch (player1Side[x][y].visuals)
            {
            case H: printf("%c", H);
                break;
            case M: printf("%c", M);
                break;
            case C: printf("%c", C);
                break;
            case B: printf("%c", B);
                break;
            case R: printf("%c", R);
                break;
            case S: printf("%c", S);
                break;
            case D: printf("%c", D);
                break;
            case W:
            default: printf("%c", W); break;
                break;
            }
        }
            printf(" | ");
        }
        printf(" |  | ");
        for (int y = 10; y > 0; y--) {
            if (player2Side[x][y].aim != 0) {
                printf("%c", player2Side[x][y].visuals);
            }
            else {
                switch (player2Side[x][y].visuals)
                {
                case H: printf("%c", H);
                    break;
                case M: printf("%c", M);
                    break;
                default: printf("%c", W); break;
                    break;
                }



            }
            printf(" | ");
        }
        printf("%d \n", x + 1);
    }
printf("         | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |10 |  |  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |10 |\n");
printf("                      Player's board                              
Computer's board\n");
}
void placeShips() {
printf("Start placing the ships by specifying what orientation ('h' for horizontal and 'v' for vertical) ship you wish to place, then putting the coordinates of where you wish to place it. 'c' for aircraft Carrier, 'd' for Destroyer, 'r' for Cruser, 's' for Submarine, and 'b' for BATTLESHIP.\n");
int *x = &a;
int *y = &b;
int c = 0;
char *i = &l;
Ship *nS = &s;
boolean isVert;
    while(c < 1) {
        isVert = false;
        scanf("%c %c", &i, &nS->type);
        if (l == 'v') {
            isVert = true;
        }
        switch (s.type)
        {
        case C: 
            s.size = 5;
            break;
        case B: 
            s.size = 4;
            break;
        case R: 
            s.size = 3;
            break;
        case S: 
            s.size = 3;
            break;
        case D: 
            s.size = 2;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
        if (a - 1 >= 10 || b - 1 >= 10 || (a + s.size >= 10 && isVert!=true) || (a + s.size >= 10 && isVert == true)){
            printf("That is out of bounds. please try again\n");
            placeShips();
            break;
        }
        else {
            for (int i = s.size; i > 0; i--) {
                if (isVert!= true) {
                    player1Side[a + i - 1][b].visuals = &nS->type;
                }
                else {
                    player1Side[a][b + i - 1].visuals = &nS->type;
                }
            }

        }
        c++;
    }
    }
    void cpuPlaceShips() {




  }
  boolean checkWinner() {

return true;


}

main() {

    for (int x = 0; x < 10;x++) {
      for (int y = 0; y < 10;y++) {
        player1Side[x][y].aim = 0;
        player2Side[x][y].aim = 0;
        player1Side[x][y].visuals = '~';
        player2Side[x][y].visuals = '~';
    }
   }
  printBoard();
  placeShips();
  printBoard();
  system("pause");


  }
```

when I run it, I expect to get the symbols of a ship in the coordinates inputted. but instead, I get this.
[image: result of]

it's really annoying and has been bugging me for hours on end. Can anyone please help me? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: It might be a good idea to provide a similar map of how you believe your code should be rendered.

Comment: An important part of the code is missing.

Comment: @RingØ thank you for telling me that. I edited it to add the important part of the code. I hope this helps in finding a solution in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code it seems you should consider `type` to be `char` and not `int` in the struct

```
typedef struct{
    int size;
    char type;   // <== not int
} Ship;
```

Then there are a few pointer confusions. In *placeShips*

```
while(c < 1) {
    isVert = false;
    scanf("%c %c", i, &nS->type); // <== not &i
```

and after the *switch*

```
    scanf("%d %d", x, y); // <== not &x &y
```

later in the *for*

```
    player1Side[a + i - 1][b].visuals = nS->type; // <== not &
}
else {
    player1Side[a][b + i - 1].visuals = nS->type; // <== not &
```

FYI, doing

```
int z;
int *p = &z;
```

makes `p` points to `z` address, so in *scanf* use directly `p` and not `&p`.

With these fixed the board should look better.

Comment: thank you so much. you helped an unbelievable amount.

Comment: Oh, sorry for that. I'm new to this sight ^^"